# Multiple distributions from one source tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging

I have a source tree that looks about like this:

```
/app/backend/module.py
/app/cli/module.py
/app/common/module.py
```

Now I want to build three packages, `app-backend`, `app-cli` and `app-common` out of this which should be distributable and be usable separately. 
I’d like to keep the code in one repository because I’d like to keep things together and it’s not so much code yet anyway.

What is the most standard and future-proof way to do this with setuptools (or is there a better fit)? I am not building for Python 2.7 or such, I would be fine if it will only work with the most current tools.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can have multiple `setup()` commands in a single `setup.py` script

In this case, you could have a single `/app/setup.py` script

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

version = '1.0.0'

setup(
    name='app-backend',
    version=version,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['cli', 'common']),
)

setup(
    name='app-cli',
    version=version,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['backend', 'common']),
)

setup(
    name='app-common',
    version=version,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['backend', 'cl']),
)
```

Running `python setup.py COMMAND` will build/install/package all three python packages

Comment: I didn’t know that you could use multiple `setup(…)` calls in one `setup.py` - can you provide a link to the docs? I implemented a solution based on your answer with multiple `setup.py` files that can be used separately, and a `setup.py` in the base dir that uses the others via `run_path` from the `runpy` module.

Answer (score 1):

> I didn’t know that you could use multiple setup(…) calls in one setup.py

You cannot, this is invalid. Please see documentation at the following location:
https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html

"The main setup config file, setup.py, should contain a single call to setuptools.setup()"

While setuptools does not initially complain, problems start occurring when you try to upload or install the package; with one packages metadata leaking into the later.